# change server date time to local date time

Tags: javascript, timezone

how to change the server date time to local date time using javascript.

I am using following function for getting the server time.Now i want to change this time to local time zone.

```
function getTimeZoneAndServerDateTime() {

    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var timeZone = web.get_regionalSettings().get_timeZone();
    context.load(timeZone);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
    function onSucceeded() {
        var info = timeZone.get_information();
        var offset = (info.get_bias() + info.get_daylightBias()) / 60.0;
        var serverDateTimeNow = new Date(new Date().getTime() - offset * 3600 * 1000).toISOString();
        console.log("serverDateTimeNow: " + serverDateTimeNow);
    },
     Failure
    );

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var serverOffsetTime = "";

function serverDefaultDateTime()
{
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.timeZone = clientContext.get_web().get_regionalSettings().get_timeZone();
    clientContext.load(timeZone);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onGetServerOffsetTimeSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onGetServerOffsetTimeSuccess(){
    var info = timeZone.get_information();  
    serverOffsetTime=(info.get_bias());
    var clientDate=new Date();
    var clientOffsetTime=(clientDate.getTimezoneOffset());
    var timedifference=(serverOffsetTime-clientOffsetTime)/60;
    var serverDateTimeNow = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (timedifference * 3600 *1000));
    return  serverDateTimeNow;
}

function removeServerOffsetTime(userDate) /* userDaTe -- is server date and time*/
{
    var clinetLocalDate=new Date();
    var clientOffsetTime=(clinetLocalDate.getTimezoneOffset());
    var timedifference=(serverOffsetTime-clientOffsetTime)/60;
    var localDateTimeNow = new Date(userDate.getTime() + (timedifference * 3600 *1000));
return localDateTimeNow;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

javascripts `Date` will give you the local time on the client.

```
var now = new Date();
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have retrieved the value form the Date field using JS, use the method "localeFormat()" to convert it to the local time zone and format as desired. Below are a few examples.

```
console.log(targetListItem.get_item('Created').localeFormat());
console.log(targetListItem.get_item('Created').localeFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```